# sending multiple tracking requests at one time

Tags: google-analytics

I am tracking some data on mobile so I'd like to save the traffic as much as possible for my users.

Say I want to update 5 tracking information at once, I wrote:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/item-a']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/item-b']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/item-c']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/item-d']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/item-e']);
```

I will send 5 requests. Is there anyway to save this by simply changing the way I track, for example, like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', ['/item-a', '/item-b', '/item-c', '/item-d', '/item-e']]);
```

Thanks for any kind of tips!

Comment: Note that you should be careful sending multiple requests to GA at a time. GA limits you to sending 10 requests every 5 seconds per visitor. So if you something like you have above in multiple places, it's increasingly likely you'll hit that limit and your requests will start getting dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest you'll get:

```
_gaq.push(
  ['_trackPageview', '/item-a'],
  ['_trackPageview', '/item-b'],
  ['_trackPageview', '/item-c'],
  ['_trackPageview', '/item-d'],
  ['_trackPageview', '/item-e']
);
```

Comment: Well, it'll push all of those items into the queue to send to Google Analytics in one go. However the data that is sent to GA is still broken out into multiple pings. GA doesn't have a way to compact multiple events into one ping. :(

Comment: Great, thanks! That's already very helpful. Currently no need to save event requests.